# Everything seems right still - SQL missing comma exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle

```
int  i =Db.getStatement().executeUpdate("insert into famous_place 
  values(img_id_seq.nextval,'"+name+"','"+
  location+"','"+dist+"','"+about+"','"+
  status+"','"+path+"',"+id+")");
```

`id` is in `long` and all others are in `string` . I can't get where is the problem and why it shows the following message for SQL in Java.

```
missing comma exception
```

Comment: Perhaps one of your values has a quote in it? This is one reason why you should use a `PreparedStatement`.

Comment: You're going to definitely want to use prepared statements here.  Notwithstanding potential SQL syntax errors, you're vulnerable to [SQL injection vulnerabilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: `missing coma exception`  I completely missed my last coma, however the doctors did not think that was exceptional.  ITYM **comma** (2x'm') there. ;)  Please copy/paste output wherever practical.

Answer (score 8):

Stop your current way of executing SQL - it's hard to read, can cause conversion issues, and most importantly is vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). I suspect that the problem is that one of your values contains a `'` which is effectively ending that quoted value within the SQL.

Instead, use a `PreparedStatement`:

```
String sql = 
   "insert into famous_place values(img_id_sq.nextval, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement statement = db.prepareStatement(sql);

statement.setString(1, name);
statement.setString(2, location);
statement.setString(3, dist);
statement.setString(4, about);
statement.setString(5, status);
statement.setString(6, path);
statement.setInt(7, id);

int rows = statement.executeUpdate();
```

(And use appropriate `try`/`finally` blocks to close the statement, connection etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Don't just construct the string and pass it straight through to `executeUpdate` <sup>(a)</sup>. The query may contain something unexpected which is causing your problem.

Instead, first place it into a string so you can print it out somehow to see if anything is wrong with it, something like:

```
string query = "insert into famous_place values(" +
    "img_id_seq.nextval,'" +
    name + "','" +
    location + "','" +
    dist + "','" +
    about + "','" +
    status + "','" +
    path + "'," +
    id + ")");
System.out.println ("[" + query + "]");
int  i =Db.getStatement().executeUpdate(query);
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> The use of raw strings in constructing queries, rather than using prepared statements, is another issue that many will bring up and you should listen to them since it can make things a lot safer. However, this is about your immediate problem of figuring out why the query isn't working as expected.

You may find that prepared statements would also fix this particular problem if you have SQL syntax tokens (like commas or quotes) in your fields, solidifying your education as to one reason *why* you shouldn't use raw strings (the other being SQL injection vulnerabilities).

Comment: Don't do this *at all* - use a prepared statement instead.

Comment: @Jon, yes, added that advice as well but finding out the actual problem would go a long way toward OP _understanding_ why they should use prepared statements.

Comment: It's much better now. When it didn't even *mention* prepared statements, I could easily see the OP just finding the problem and working around it somehow, keeping the awful code.